# Как различать системные push notifications от тех которые адресуются юзеру?

Tags: java, android, уведомления, android-notification

Мое приложение работает с сервером. Сервер может отправлять системные уведомления те которые юзер не должен видеть, а может отправлять уведомления для диалога с юзером.

Так вот единственное, что мне придумалось это в самом сообщении обозначить какой нибудь флаг и по нему ориентироваться.

Погуглил и не нашел никаких советов от гугла по этому поводу.

Но решил узнать у разработчиков с опытом, есть ли какая нибудь стандартная реализация или через флаги делать?

Answer (score 1):

никто не знает, что такое у вас "уведомления". Если это push notifications, то вы можете на клиенте составить перечень типов сообщений, которые нужно показывать юзеру, и смотреть, содержится ли тип конкретного сообщения в списке показываемых. Но лучше это сделать на сервере, т. к. если у вас появится новый тип, и вы забудете его вниести в список, то он не будет показываться.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду тип сообщения который я получаю тут `gcm.getMessageType(intent);`?  На данный момент у меня 3 стандартных типа это ESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR, MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED, MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE. Но `gsm` сам присваивает тип при отправке... или когда сервер отправляет notification то можно присвоить ему свой тип?